# Remove duplicated from list of dict- python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have list of dictionaries, I want to remove duplicates from that list. How to do that ?

```
a = [
 {'dtstart': '2014-09-10T08:00:00',
  'end': datetime.datetime(2014, 9, 10, 9, 0),
  'location': 'Brady Auditorium, B-131',
  'partial_date': datetime.date(2014, 9, 10),
  'photo': 'http://tools.medicine.yale.edu/portal/stream?id=01a331e2-42be-4622-b072-0c42b55b436e&w=540&h=700',
  'start': datetime.datetime(2014, 9, 10, 8, 0),
  'stream': '01a331e2-42be-4622-b072-0c42b55b436e',
  'summary': 'Clinical Neuroscience Grand Rounds: "The Mechanism of Impaired Consciousness of Absence Seizures"',
  'uid': '2d671415-c666-498f-a401-01652a08e4b3'},
 {'dtstart': '2014-09-10T08:00:00',
  'end': datetime.datetime(2014, 9, 10, 9, 0),
  'location': 'Brady Auditorium, B-131',
  'partial_date': datetime.date(2014, 9, 10),
  'photo': 'http://tools.medicine.yale.edu/portal/stream?id=ccf667b2-b5a0-464f-8797-66eb36b0bf6c&w=540&h=700',
  'start': datetime.datetime(2014, 9, 10, 8, 0),
  'stream': 'ccf667b2-b5a0-464f-8797-66eb36b0bf6c',
  'summary': 'Clinical Neuroscience Grand Rounds: "The Mechanism of Impaired Consciousness of Absence Seizures"',
  'uid': '2d671415-c666-498f-a401-01652a08e4b3'}
]
```

What I have tried is ,

```
>>> [dict(t) for t in set([tuple(d.items()) for d in a])]
```

But still returning duplicate elements.

Comment: How do you know they are duplicates?

Comment: Based on 'uid' key of dict.

Comment: they have different stream value is it fine to pick any one

Comment: create a temp dict using UID as key and call `.values()` on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just try the following code:

```
{document['uid']: document for document in a}.values()
```

For every `uuid` you will get the latest document. If you're looking for the first entries, try this:

```
{document['uid']: document for document in a[::-1]}.values()
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a dictionary comprehension to create a dictionary with `uid` as keys and each dictionary as values. Then extract the values to return a list of unique dictionaries as keyed by `uid`.

```
>>> a=[{'end': datetime.datetime(2014, 9, 10, 9, 0), 'uid': '2d671415-c666-498f-a401-01652a08e4b3', 'stream': '01a331e2-42be-4622-b072-0c42b55b436e', 'photo': 'http://tools.medicine.yale.edu/portal/stream?id=01a331e2-42be-4622-b072-0c42b55b436e&w=540&h=700', 'partial_date': datetime.date(2014, 9, 10), 'summary': 'Clinical Neuroscience Grand Rounds: "The Mechanism of Impaired Consciousness of Absence Seizures"', 'start': datetime.datetime(2014, 9, 10, 8, 0), 'location': 'Brady Auditorium, B-131', 'dtstart': '2014-09-10T08:00:00'}, {'end': datetime.datetime(2014, 9, 10, 9, 0), 'uid': '2d671415-c666-498f-a401-01652a08e4b3', 'stream': 'ccf667b2-b5a0-464f-8797-66eb36b0bf6c', 'photo': 'http://tools.medicine.yale.edu/portal/stream?id=ccf667b2-b5a0-464f-8797-66eb36b0bf6c&w=540&h=700', 'partial_date': datetime.date(2014, 9, 10), 'summary': 'Clinical Neuroscience Grand Rounds: "The Mechanism of Impaired Consciousness of Absence Seizures"', 'start': datetime.datetime(2014, 9, 10, 8, 0), 'location': 'Brady Auditorium, B-131', 'dtstart': '2014-09-10T08:00:00'}]
>>> {d['uid']: d for d in a}.values()
[{'dtstart': '2014-09-10T08:00:00',
  'end': datetime.datetime(2014, 9, 10, 9, 0),
  'location': 'Brady Auditorium, B-131',
  'partial_date': datetime.date(2014, 9, 10),
  'photo': 'http://tools.medicine.yale.edu/portal/stream?id=ccf667b2-b5a0-464f-8797-66eb36b0bf6c&w=540&h=700',
  'start': datetime.datetime(2014, 9, 10, 8, 0),
  'stream': 'ccf667b2-b5a0-464f-8797-66eb36b0bf6c',
  'summary': 'Clinical Neuroscience Grand Rounds: "The Mechanism of Impaired Consciousness of Absence Seizures"',
  'uid': '2d671415-c666-498f-a401-01652a08e4b3'}]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try appending the uids to a temporary list  and verify with present dictionary

```
import datetime

a=[{'end': datetime.datetime(2014, 9, 10, 9, 0), 'uid': '2d671415-c666-498f-a401-01652a08e4b3', 'stream': '01a331e2-42be-4622-b072-0c42b55b436e', 'photo': 'http://tools.medicine.yale.edu/portal/stream?id=01a331e2-42be-4622-b072-0c42b55b436e&w=540&h=700', 'partial_date': datetime.date(2014, 9, 10), 'summary': 'Clinical Neuroscience Grand Rounds: "The Mechanism of Impaired Consciousness of Absence Seizures"', 'start': datetime.datetime(2014, 9, 10, 8, 0), 'location': 'Brady Auditorium, B-131', 'dtstart': '2014-09-10T08:00:00'},
   {'end': datetime.datetime(2014, 9, 10, 9, 0), 'uid': '2d671415-c666-498f-a401-01652a08e4b3', 'stream': 'ccf667b2-b5a0-464f-8797-66eb36b0bf6c', 'photo': 'http://tools.medicine.yale.edu/portal/stream?id=ccf667b2-b5a0-464f-8797-66eb36b0bf6c&w=540&h=700', 'partial_date': datetime.date(2014, 9, 10), 'summary': 'Clinical Neuroscience Grand Rounds: "The Mechanism of Impaired Consciousness of Absence Seizures"', 'start': datetime.datetime(2014, 9, 10, 8, 0), 'location': 'Brady Auditorium, B-131', 'dtstart': '2014-09-10T08:00:00'}]

uuids = set() # temperary set holds UID
final=[]

for i in a:
    if i['uid'] not in uuids:
        final.append(i)
        uuids.add(i['uid'])
print final
```

Comment: `set` looks like a better candidate for the role of uid storage.

Comment: Your code is ineffective as it has `O(N^2)` complexity. Use `set` to store `uuid`s to achieve `O(N)`.

Comment: @Vladimir can you edit my answer.and show how to implement set.

Comment: @sundarnataraj, done. Actually the difference in speed will become visible on hundreds of thousands documents in `a`.

Comment: @Vladimir thank you.learned some thing :)